# Modifying Python Class Definition so it isn't Case Sensitive

Tags: python

I have a question regarding modifying a class so that it is not case sensitive and ignores spaces.

Since this is my homework I am NOT looking for the answer, only some help.

The assignment has me modifying the `checkAnswer` so it isn't case sensitive.

The homework's hint is to use string `replace`, `upper` and `lower`.

[the homework problem itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ2Md.png)

What I've been thinking:

```
  def checkAnswer(self, response) :
      responseStr=str(response)
      responseStr.lower()
      responseStr.replace(" ","")
      answer=str(self)
      answer.lower()
      answer.replace(" ","")
  if answer == responseStr:
      return self._answer = correctResponse
```

However I am lost on how to compare the `reponseStr` to the correct answer which is housed in a different file.

I can include the test file if it's necessary.

---

```
from random import randint

## A question with a text and an answer.; ignores case and spaces.#
class Question :
## Constructs a question with empty question and answer strings.
#
def __init__(self) :
   self._text = ""
   self._answer = ""

##  Sets the question text.
#   @param questionText the text of this question
#
def setText(self, questionText) :   
   self._text = questionText

## Sets the answer for this question.#
   @param correctResponse the answer

def setAnswer(self, correctResponse) :
   self._answer = correctResponse

## Checks a given response for correctness.
#  @param response the response to check
#  @return True if the response was correct, False otherwise
#
def checkAnswer(self, response) :
   return response == self._answer

## Displays this question.#
def display(self) :
   print(self._text)         

## A question with numeric answer.#
class NumericQuestion(Question) :
    pass
## A question with multiple choices presented in random order.#
class ChoiceQuestion(Question) :
    pass
```

---

this is the file in which I am supposed to read the input from and compared it to the correct answer.
    ##
    #HW10.py holds the class definitions for: Question, NumericQuestion
    #  ChoiceQuestion

```
from HW10 import Question, NumericQuestion, ChoiceQuestion

def main() :     
    stem = "What is the value of 10/3 ?"
    nq = NumericQuestion()       
    nq.setText(stem)
    nq.display()
    nq.setAnswer(10/3)
    for i in range(5):
        response = input("Enter answer to two decimal places: ")
        print(response)
        if nq.checkAnswer(response):
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

   print('\n')  
   q = Question()
   q.setText("Who is the inventor of Python?")
   q.setAnswer("Guido van Rossum")
   q.display()
   response = input("Enter answer: ")
   if q.checkAnswer(response):
      print("Correct!")
   else:
      print("Incorrect")

   print('\n')

   mcq = ChoiceQuestion()
   mcq.setText("In which country was the inventor of Python born?")
   mcq.addChoice("Australia", False)
   mcq.addChoice("Canada", False)
   mcq.addChoice("Netherlands", True)
   mcq.addChoice("United States", False)
   for i in range(3) :
       presentQuestion(mcq)

 ## Presents a question to the user and checks the response.
 #  @param q the question
 #
def presentQuestion(q) :
q.display()   # Uses dynamic method lookup.
response = input("Your answer: ")
if q.checkAnswer(response):
   print("Correct")
else:
   print("Incorrect")   # checkAnswer uses dynamic method lookup.

# Start the program.
main()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the assignment / your code. Esp what do you mean by *compare the reponseStr to the correct answer which is housed in a different file.* You mean an external file you read in? Or where is that correct answer?

Comment: Is there a reason you changed the return of CheckAnswer to `return self._answer = correctResponse`? That will not work with the test cases, you need to return a `True` or `False`, just like in the exercise files. Why not just leave it as `return response == self._answer`? That will return True if they are the same, and False if they are not. Then, your test script will print the appropriate response.